# Adding an image to excel using openXML

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml

I have been trying to ad an image to a cell in a worksheet using openXML.  Most solutions I have found while searching use code from or similar to the code at PolymathProgrammer website:

http://polymathprogrammer.com/2009/11/30/how-to-insert-an-image-in-excel-open-xml/

When I try this I get an error regarding NonVisualDrawingProperties, like this:
[image]

even though my usings should incluse it:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  Or is there some easier code I could be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there are several `NonVisualDrawingProperties` in various namespaces and it's ambiguous as to which one you want here.

You can solve this by fully qualifying the name:

```
var nvdp = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet.NonVisualDrawingProperties();
```

You can also [alias the using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) to prevent having to type quite so much:

```
using SPD = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Spreadsheet;
...
var nvdp = new SPD.NonVisualDrawingProperties();
```